# Styling broken image alt-text with CSS

Tags: html, css, broken-image

For my e-commerce site I'm using lazy loading for images with `lazysizes`. To provide conform `img` tags these contain an empty `src="data:,"` suggest by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53365710/672452) thread which is really neat.

So all lazy loaded images are display as a broken image with `alt` text until they reach view port. The problem is, that these `alt` texts contain product names which can be really long, so this text overflows image bounds sometimes and breaks layout (i.e. responsive):

[image]

Is there a **cross-browser** solution out there to style `alt` texts for images?

**EDIT** It's important to mention, that I'm talking about `alt` texts containing less to no whitespaces, so it would not line-break automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I style an image's ALT text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101743/can-i-style-an-images-alt-text-with-css)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava The thread mentioned is about font color. The problem here is, that text is overflowing the boundaries.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava You mean, a `word-break: break-all` or `overflow: hidden` will also apply to `alt` text and will work in all browsers?

Comment: Not sure actually, found a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731484/can-i-wrap-img-alt-text

Comment: If you're using javascript, I think it can be easier. Try to cut the text to a variable and wait until the image is loaded successful, then pasting it back.

Comment: Javascript is evaluated on load first, so this would lead to broken layout nevertheless until DOM is loaded completely. A pure CSS solution is the only option.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava the other link is related to texts that contain any whitespaces. For these cases a fixed width of a container may work. As I have no influence on the product names, there are often names without any whitespace (see my example). And in that case a fixed width is ignored, text will overflow container.

Comment: It seems that `overflow:hidden` will work in most cases (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461916/img-size-when-displaying-alt-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. Simply use `word-break: break-word;` on `img` tags

```css
img {
  border: 3px solid red;
  max-width: 250px;
}
.wrap-broken {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<img alt="LLOYD Herren Businessschuh Don, Männer Schnürhalbschuhe,Halbschuh,Schnürschuh,Schnürer,Derby Schnürung,Anzugschuh,Office,Büro,REH/Stone,5.5 UK / 38.5 EU" src="https://www.kleiderliebe.de/herren/schuhe/anzugschuhe/lloyd-herren-businessschuh-don-maenner-schnuerhalbschuhe-halbschuh-schnuerschuh-schnuerer-derby-schnuerung.img">
<br><br>
<img class="wrap-broken" alt="LLOYD Herren Businessschuh Don, Männer Schnürhalbschuhe,Halbschuh,Schnürschuh,Schnürer,Derby Schnürung,Anzugschuh,Office,Büro,REH/Stone,5.5 UK / 38.5 EU" src="https://www.kleiderliebe.de/herren/schuhe/anzugschuhe/lloyd-herren-businessschuh-don-maenner-schnuerhalbschuhe-halbschuh-schnuerschuh-schnuerer-derby-schnuerung.img">
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any great CSS-only solution here. As others pointed out in the comments, a small amount of JS would go a long way here.

That said, here's some simple CSS which improves the appearance of the alt tag on missing images.

The key styles are the `white-space: pre-wrap;`, `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, and `overflow: hidden;`. The combo of these will automatically break long strings, add an ellipsis to long strings, and cut-off the alt text vertically.

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<img src="missing.jpg" width="200" height="100" alt="A really long description of an image that won't load">

<img src="missing.jpg" width="200" height="100" alt="An alt tag containing a URL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434846/styling-broken-image-alt-text-with-css ">
```